# Regex for validate a website URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

The following regex:

```
(http|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?
```

Is matched for the following:

```
https://something.com, 
https://www.something.com, 
http://something.com, 
http://www.something.com
```

But the following is should not be match which is matched for the current regex:

```
https://www.something, http://www.something
```

And also the following is should be matched which is not matched for the current regex:

```
something.com, www.something.com
```

And also it matched for any domain, what I want to do is only accept known domains (such as: .com, .net, .biz etc).

How can I improve the above regex?

Comment: ^(http|https|ftp|)\://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z](:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$

Comment: but *www.something* also will match, I guess

Comment: Not sure it is a good pattern, I will only post as a comment: [`https?:\/\/(?!www\.[^\s.]+\b(?!\.))[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?`](https://regex101.com/r/mY6rC3/1). Based on yours. Excludes a URL that has `www.` after `http`, and then one part without a dot up to the word boundary not followed with a dot.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, not sure if I am allowed to say this, but from the following link that you have mentioned: https://regex101.com/r/mY6rC3/2 is allowed for `http://www.something. and https://www.something. `, but it is not allowed for `www.something.com or something.com` and also, is there anyway to only allow the user enter only known domain (eg: .com, .net, .biz, .org, etc). Thanks

Comment: Hi @Khazratbek, I have tried your code, but it is not working well for me.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you need. To match URLs in a comma-delimited list? If yes, why not to split with a comma to get a list of individual strings that are easier to manipulate? If you are just trying to extract URLs from a larger text, try [`https?:\/\/(?!www\.[^\s.]+(?:[.,]\B))\S+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/mY6rC3/3). Then you can filter against the TLDs with `/\.(?:com|biz|...)$/.test(url_found)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: no Wiktor, I just want that `www.something.com` or `something.com` is allowed also in the above regex that you provided. And also only allow certain domain name (eg: .com, .net, .biz, .org, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `(:?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?)?[-a-z0-9]+\.(?:com|gov|org|net|edu|biz)`

https://regex101.com/r/bH7eL5/2

Comment: Thank you very much @siete.sh. It is working as expected and what I want it to be. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this regex validator. I used it in combination with another to get what I wanted. Last piece of the puzzle. Thank you.@matsib.dev